# How to change "✓" color in a bootstrap checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, colors, bootstrap-5

I have the following html code styled with bootstrap:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto">
    <ul class="list-group">
      {% for sl in my_list %}
      <li
        class="list-group-item my-lg-2 my-1 list-group-item-secondary bg-dark text-light"
      >
        <input
          class="form-check-input me-1"
          type="checkbox"
          value=""
          id="checkbox_{{ loop.index0 }}"
          style="
            border-top-left-radius: inherit;
            border-top-right-radius: inherit;
          "
        />
        <label
          class="form-check-label"
          for="checkbox_{{ loop.index0 }}"
          >{{ sl.description }}</label
        >
      </li>

      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to change the checkbox ticks button. I also defined some style for my checkboxes:

```css
@keyframes shadowAnimation {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.9);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

.animate-checkbox {
  animation: shadowAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input:focus-visible,
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input:focus {
  border-color: #212529;
  border: var(--bs-border-width) solid #ff9800 !important;
}
```

And animation is controlled by javascript. I don't want these option are overwritten, but i can achieve to have the tick colored. 
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I'm now able to obatin it in a project without bootstrap:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
      <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li
            class="list-group-item my-lg-2 my-1 list-group-item-secondary bg-dark text-light"
          >
            <input
              class="form-check-input me-1 animate-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              value=""
              id="checkbox_{{ loop.index0 }}"
            />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox_{{ loop.index0 }}"
              >prova</label
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
@keyframes shadowAnimation {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.9);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

/* Add your animation to the checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input.animate-checkbox {
  /* Your animation styles here */
  animation: shadowAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
  color: #212529;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  text-align: center;

  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 25%;

  border: 1px solid #212529;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

When I use bootstrap, instead, a white "✓" is visible behind the black one, that appears in the center of the square. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in a very simple way without adding several CSS rules. Inspecting the code, I could see that bootstrap used this rule:

```css
.form-check-input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  --bs-form-check-bg-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='m6 10 3 3 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

And disabling this option by the browser console, the tick disappears. Making researches, I found out that the tick is customable. In particular, to change the color, I just needed to provide the correct `stroke` field. In my case, to set the color to `#212529` I had to use `stroke='%23212529'`. 

Note that the `#` is coded in the unicode browser format `%23`. 

In the end, just added the following css rule in my stylesheet:

```css
input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  --bs-form-check-bg-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23212529' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='m6 10 3 3 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
```

I could able to customize also the tick using a text:

```css
--bs-form-check-bg-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20'><text x='5' y='15' font-size='16' font-family='Arial' fill='%23212529' text-anchor='middle'>%E2%9C%93</text></svg>") !important;
```

This will use the "✓" tick as mark. Note that the position of the text may not be centered in the square: just need to play with the `x` and `y` to center it.